# My application keeps on crashing using Webview?

Tags: android, webview

I'm just testing my application at the moment. However, it keeps on crashing on the loading screen. Once it loads it redirects to the login or users account if they have already logged in.

However, I keep getting these error messages in android studios console log when built the application.

```
W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/chrisbeckett.********/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory

// I've put the stars as I can't show the name of the application yet. 
W/cr_AwContentsClient: Denied starting an intent without a user gesture, URI http://********.********.com/login
```

My current code:

```
package chrisbeckett.**********;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;// Instance of WebChromeClient for handling all chrome functions.
    private volatile WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(100 * 1000 * 1000);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://********.*********.com/loading");
    }

    /**
     * Set the WebChromeClient.
     * @param client An implementation of WebChromeClient.
     */
    public void setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient client) {
        mWebChromeClient = client;
    }
}
```

Further information:

My code works on all web browsers on a desktop when viewing it in a mobile mode in the inspector when testing before putting it in App format.

If you require any more information please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Denied starting an intent without a user gesture Webview Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048945/denied-starting-an-intent-without-a-user-gesture-webview-android)

Comment: Just add this line `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`

Comment: @AbhishekSingh That didn't work. Comes up with the same error message

Comment: @ChrisBeckett add this line before setting chromeclient

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try  below code this may work

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;                
    }

});
```

Comment: not working for me. I am loading html file from assest folder

Comment: You saved my life bro.
Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it for Android N

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: You saved my life bro.
Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag
```

add above line in your manifest.xml  file.